# How to take average of loading time for multiple files

Tags: python, numpy, load, mean

The code prints the loading time of each sample and I want to give me average of loading time of files.

```
for i in range(10):

    t0 = time.time()
    test = io.loadmat(f"Y{i+1}.mat",squeeze_me=True)['Ar']
    a=print(time.time()-t0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum()`:

```
tms = []

for i in range(10):
    t0 = time.time()
    tms.append(t0)
    do_something()

avg = sum(tms)/len(tms)
print(avg)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n=10
total_time = 0
for i in range(n):

    t0 = time.time()
    test = io.loadmat(f"Y{i+1}.mat",squeeze_me=True)['Ar']
    total_time += time.time()-t0

prnit(total_time/n)
```

You can also use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)